# Word-wrap not working in LI element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to wrap the words automatically within width.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:298px;margin:15px 0 0 0;">
     <li>option 1 </li>
     <li>option 2 option 2 option 2 option 2 option 2 option 2</li>
</ul>
```

It's now working fine with `white-space:normal`

```
ul li{
     white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: can you give me the jsfiddle of what are you using as CSS

Comment: It's working - http://jsfiddle.net/APuAE/

Comment: Can you share full html and css

Comment: thank u so much for reply.. now its working fine with 'white-space:normal'

Comment: white-space:normal did it for me as well.

Answer (score 17):

Please Try it...

```
ul li {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Google kept showing this answer and this didn't work for me. This other answer that was remarkably difficult did work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157981/css-how-to-wrap-text-in-li

Answer (score 6):

Add white-space:normal to your CSS element:

```
  word-break: normal;
  white-space: normal;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me as it wraps correctly with or without whitespace:

```
li {
    word-break: break-all;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use `word-wrap:break-word;` works perfectly fine for me here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4373/)