# Css how to wrap text in li

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap my text in my slide menu. I have ul max-width 200px, but when I write longer text, then my text is not visible ( now i added overflow: visible to show You what I mean ). How to wrap this?

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width: 200px" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>
```

And css now :

```
<style>

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;

        max-height: 0;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden; <-- here i was trying to add  word-wrap: break-word; but it doesn'twork   
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
        max-height: 200px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: also add width for the word-wrap

Comment: How did you style that item divider?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` on `li`. check updated snippet below..

```css
.dropdown-menu li, .dropdown-menu li a {
    white-space: normal;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width: 200px" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header trying to write something</li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="disabled"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</nav>
```

Comment: This works without the word-wrap: break-word; but it doesn't work without white-space: normal;

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
.dropdown-header {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [when you should use important](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used).

Comment: I use !important in case wenus not change his code, for nothing else, however, thank you for the information.

Comment: Setting the line-height to normal did the trick for me along with the above lines. Also, don't think you need !important. Worked for me without !important.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this code

```
.dropdown-menu li, .dropdown-menu li a {
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```